# How to integrate Live Activity into Objective C projects?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios16, widgetliveactivity

I have a food delivery app similar to Uber Eat it was developed in Objective C now the requirement is to implement the Live activity for tracking the Active orders. As i tried Live activity over the Swift it is working fine on all IOS Devices but when i implement that swift code into Objective C using all the standards by Bridging between Swift and Obj C copied the same code, There is no Error or Warning i am seeing in Live activity functionality in Objective C, but Live Activity UI can't seen on Lockscreen even i have checked in settings my app is showing that it supports Live Activity but no view.

Can somebody help me out in that how to integrate live activity into Objective C project?

I tried Swift Code in a separate app it works Fine and showing Live Activity both in Simulator and on real Device.

I copied the same code followed the same methods into my old Objective C Project but no Live activity is going to be shown. even no error no warnings. also declared the NSSupportsLiveActivities to YES in Project info.plist file. Also getting the Activity registration Token in logs. but on viewing the live activity its not showing anywhere.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can integrate it by using swift bridging header,

**let me explain** ,

once you add live activity widget in project , you will able to see one swiftUI file for live activity's UI , now you need to create one swift file for 'ActivityAttributes' in swift , as well need to create one swift file where you will implement all needed methods and code for live activity , now  crate bridging header to use your swift code in objective c project , import swift file in a obj-c view controller where you want to implement live activity and call needed functions according your feature flaw,
I've implement same way in my project and it's **working well** .